# What's wrong with negative values in this MySQL IN clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, view

I have a view like this:

```
TABLE_TYPE
(code,name)
(1,'Computer')
(2,'Television')
(3,'Radio')

TABLE_THING
(code,name,type=TABLE_TYPE:code)
(-9999, 'ThingFirst',1)
(1,'Thing1',1)
(2,'Thing2',2)
(3,'Thing3',2)
(4,'Thing4',3)
(5,'Thing5',1)

VIEW_THINGS
(code,name,thingtype)
(-9999, 'ThingFirst','Computer')
(1,'Thing1','Computer')
(2,'Thing2','Television')
(3,'Thing3','Television')
(4,'Thing4','Radio')
(5,'Thing5','Computer')
```

Query:

```
select * from VIEW_THINGS where code in (-9999,1,2,3,4,5)
```

Result is:

```
(-9999, 'ThingFirst',NULL)
```

Result should be:

```
(-9999, 'ThingFirst','Computer')
(1,'Thing1','Computer')
(2,'Thing2','Television')
(3,'Thing3','Television')
(4,'Thing4','Radio')
(5,'Thing5','Computer')
```

WHAT'S WRONG????

Tip1: When I quit the negative value (-9999) from the IN clause I get this:

```
(1,'Thing1','Computer')
(2,'Thing2','Television')
(3,'Thing3','Television')
(4,'Thing4','Radio')
(5,'Thing5','Computer')
```

Tip2: If I do the select from the total view results I get the correct data:

```
select * from (select * from VIEW_THINGS as T) where code in (-9999,1,2,3,4,5)
```

Results:

```
(-9999, 'ThingFirst','Computer')
(1,'Thing1','Computer')
(2,'Thing2','Television')
(3,'Thing3','Television')
(4,'Thing4','Radio')
(5,'Thing5','Computer')
```

Comment: What is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_TYPE; SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_THING; SHOW CREATE TABLE VIEW_THINGS;`?

Answer (score 1):

Full test script:

```
create table TABLE_TYPE(code int,name varchar(20));
insert table_type values
(1,'Computer'),
(2,'Television'),
(3,'Radio');

create table TABLE_THING(code int,name varchar(20),type int);
insert table_thing values
(-9999, 'ThingFirst',1),
(1,'Thing1',1),
(2,'Thing2',2),
(3,'Thing3',2),
(4,'Thing4',3),
(5,'Thing5',1);

create table VIEW_THINGS(code int, name varchar(20),thingtype varchar(20));
insert view_things values
(-9999, 'ThingFirst','Computer'),
(1,'Thing1','Computer'),
(2,'Thing2','Television'),
(3,'Thing3','Television'),
(4,'Thing4','Radio'),
(5,'Thing5','Computer');

select * from VIEW_THINGS where code in (-9999,1,2,3,4,5);
```

Output

```
"code";"name";"thingtype"
"-9999";"ThingFirst";"Computer"
"1";"Thing1";"Computer"
"2";"Thing2";"Television"
"3";"Thing3";"Television"
"4";"Thing4";"Radio"
"5";"Thing5";"Computer"
```

Since that works, I'll take a punt that VIEW_THINGS is a view that joins the two tables. Let's see

```
create view view_things2
as
select t.code, t.name, y.name thingtype
from table_thing t
inner join table_type y on y.code = t.type
;
select * from VIEW_THINGS2 where code in (-9999,1,2,3,4,5);
```

Output: as above

This is as far as we can go with the info you have provided.

Answer (score -1):

did you try with changing order like

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW_THINGS WHERE code IN (1,2,3,4,5,-9999)
```

Comment: what's the problem with the order

Comment: @Cris i m just asking,in mySQL the word `IN` is an alias for `= ANY`, please try with that

Comment: I didn't downvote you but I suspect you got downvoted because the order of items in an `IN` clause has no bearing at all on the results returned. There is no reason to believe your suggestion would help.